# JFreeChart Creating layered Time Series

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a requirement to show time-series data as layered bar chart. Is it possible with JFreeChart? Any pointers would be really helpful.

The data would be a list of: (TS, X1, X2), where I've to plot X1 for a given Timestamp (TS) and X2 would basically serve as the label for the given value of X1.

Edit: Also, for the same TS, there might exist different X1 values. The idea is to denote all these X1 values as layered bars against the same TS.

Here's somewhat of an example of what I want:

[image: chart image]
.

(so instead of category, I'll have TS in X-axis)

Comment: Can you post a mock-up or cite a [sample/demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html)?

Comment: I just edited my post to add more clarity and a screenshot of something close to what i want.

Comment: @Sujay - what do you mean you by wanting the TS in the x-axis? You want to label the bars on the x-axis with dates/times (in which case you can use `CategoryDataSet`), or you want the spacing between the bars on the x-axis to reflect the timings of the TS (in which case you want something like a `TimeAxis`)?

Comment: Why not use the approach shown in `OverlaidBarChartDemo2` itself?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a BarChart (with x-axis determined by time) with the bars labelled with their values. You don't need to add a new data series for the labels, but modify the rendering of the plot.

Here's a simple example:

```
public class LabelledBarChartTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    dataset.addValue(10.0, "Series", new Integer(2010));
    dataset.addValue(20.0, "Series", new Integer(2011));
    dataset.addValue(30.0, "Series", new Integer(2012));
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(null,null,null,dataset,
      PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true,true,false);
    CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
    CategoryItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();

    // label the points
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    CategoryItemLabelGenerator generator = new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator(
        StandardXYItemLabelGenerator.DEFAULT_ITEM_LABEL_FORMAT, format, format);
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(generator);
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);

    frame.setContentPane(new ChartPanel(chart));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Credit where credit is due - I got the labelling example from this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jfreechartdemo).

Comment: Thanks @amaidment for the sample. However this is not quite what I want. I just updated my initial post, perhaps this will give you a better idea of what I want to do.